# Webpack extract multi tenant translation from XLIFF

Tags: webpack, xliff

I have a php web application with translations and multiple tenants :

```
translations
  /common
    /messages.en.xlf
    /messages.fr.xlf
    /messages.es.xlf
    /thing.en.xlf
    /thing.fr.xlf
    /thing.es.xlf
  /TenantA
    /messages.fr.xlf
  /TenantB
    /thing.es.xlf
```

Sometimes, TenantA or TenantB needs to specialise a subset of resnames of a xlf file.

For TenantA, each key in `translations/TenantA/messages.fr.xlf` needs to override the key in `translations/common/messages.fr.xlf` and get every other value from `translations/common/messages.fr.xlf`.

Every file and every key is present in `translations/common`, and are in every language.

I am looking for a way to do that in javascript, through webpack.

In this list, Symfony calls "messages" and "thing" a domain, so I'll use the word domain.

To solve this issue, I am looking for a way to watch changes in the /translations/ folder, and compile for each tenant and for each domain a single map having everything in this domain ; so that I can use in my assets :

```
import translations from 'translations/messages'
```

with translations looking like :

```
{"fr":{...}, "en":{...}, "es":{...}}

or

{"key":{"en":"value", "fr":"valeur", "es":"..."}}
```

and from specialised keys.

How can I plug something to compile these files into json ?

My webpack.config.json looks like this :

```
const tenants = ['TenantA', 'TenantB', ...];
const modules = []

tenants.foreach(tenant =>
{
   modules.push(/*webpack config accumulation*/)
})


module.exports = modules
```